# Manifest for home intent and launcher intent

Tags: android

What I have done is made a home screen application. Aka when you press home, it goes back to my app.

What I am struggling with though, is adding a normal launcher side to it, aka making it appear as an app in the apps menu. My intention is to create a simple screen that tells you and provides button access to change the home default settings. A wizard/setup guide in effect.

However, I am not sure how to have both together in one app, as it is something new to me.

The home bit works, it is the second activity that doesnt.

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are those activities wraped with Application tag?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic Yes, this is just a snippet from my manifest. Its all funcional, except for the intent filter I assume, for launcherActivity

Comment: if i understood, you want to launch LauncherActivity when the user click on App icon from Apps menu. Try adding android.intent.action.MAIN to the intent filter to the LauncherActivity

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic Thanks that worked. Thought i had tried it, but re-tried. and successful thanks :)

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, however, I wish for them to access it before my homescreen is set. So they can choose mine, with ease to do so.

Comment: Nice, im making this an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the android.intent.action.MAIN inside the LauncherActivity Intent filter so it looks like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Given it a +1 for now, It doesn't always work, sometimes it will just launch the home screen when i press the app button. Need it to always be the launcher activity. But is a step forward.

Comment: have you tried to remove the intent main from the HomeActivity?

Comment: Without the main in home, it no longer appears as a valid home screen option. :(

Comment: Setting both to `MAIN` and `DEFAULT`, with one as `HOME` and one as `LAUNCHER` , may have done the trick